# Integral and dominated convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let us define $g_n(x)= n\chi_{[0,n^{-3}]}(x)$.  I am looking for help to  answers the following problem

$(a)$ Show that if $f$ $\epsilon$ $L^2([0,1])$ then $\int_0^1f(x)g_n(x)dx \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow 0.$

$(b)$ Show the there exist $f$ $\epsilon$ $L^1([0,1])$ such that  $\int_0^1f(x)g_n(x)dx \nrightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow 0.$

I think the $1^{st}$ problem can be done by Dominated Convergence Theorem.Here the pointwise limit of $f(x)g_n(x)$  is  $0$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The Dominated convergence theorem will not help you. It was good for a), it would also show that b) is not possible.

For a) use Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality:
$$
\Bigl|\int_0^1f\,g_n\Bigr|\le n\int_0^{1/n^3}|f|\le n\Bigl(\int_0^{1/n^3}|f|^2\Bigr)^{1/2}\Bigl(\int_0^{1/n^3}1\Bigr)^{1/2}\le\|f\|_2\,n^{-1/2}.
$$

For b), take $f(x)=x^{-a}$, $2/3<a<1$.